# Can anybody explain me this simple Python code?

Tags: python, numpy

I have simple function which returns matrix of zeros and ones. I can't understand how line: out[range(n), vec] = 1 works. Vector v can have values from 0 to 9.

```
import numpy as np

def one_hot_encode(vec, vals=10):

    n = len(vec)
    out = np.zeros((n, vals))
    out[range(n), vec] = 1
    return out

v = [1,2,3,1,3,5,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,1,3,5,7,8,9,1,2,3]
one_hot_encode(v, 10)
```

Comment: put a `print` wherever you like and check `help(np)` ?

Comment: That line uses [NumPy's advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Read the documentation for more information. In this case, it selects all elements `out[0, vec[0]]`, `out[1, vec[1]]`, `out[2, vec[2]]`, etc. and sets them to value 1.

Answer (score 1):

the line line: out[range(n), vec] = 1 is placing the one corresponding to vec values i.e. if vec has first value 1 then in out matrix first row and second column(value +1) will be assigned as 1. if 4rt value is 1 then 4rt row and second column will be assigned 1.